# Exclude special charcters with Regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to get version number of my assembly. I use regex for it and here is my pattern.

```
  $pattern = '\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\("(.*)"\)\]'
```

It works good but in AssemblyInfo.cs and AssemblyInfo.vb there are some special characters as example

in cs file

```
// by using the '*' as shown below:
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("3.7.1.0")]
```

in .vb file

```
' <Assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")> 
  <Assembly: AssemblyVersion("3.2.0.0")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")>
```

So I want to exclude // and ' charachters in my pattern. I tried to exclude it with [^//] but it does not work. I tried something else but it did not work either.

And the second question is

in .vb file, there are different starting.

```
<Assembly: AssemblyVersion("3.2.0.0")>
```

and in c# file there are different starting

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("3.7.1.0")]
```

How i can include also vb version into my pattern?

Where is the problem?

Comment: Anchor the pattern at the start of the line with only optional whitespace preceding it: `^\s*\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\("(.*)"\)\]`

Comment: But, I don't see `/` in your version string

Comment: Do you literally need to match the entire line for the language that you are using the pattern in?  Can you not just match from `ssembly: ...`?  Is this part of a larger body of text?  If you only need to capture everything inside of parenthesis, this can be much simpler.

Comment: are you using php? there is no language tag.

Comment: I am using powershell for that. Because I need it in TFS step. The problem has been solved with Oleksandr Muliar's code. Thank you for your replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) if your library supports it

```
(?<!\/\/\s|\'\s)\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\("(.*)"\)\]
```

Edit:
For matching different brackets you can just use `[variant1|variant2]` syntax

```
(?<!\/\/\s|\'\s)[<\[][Aa]ssembly: AssemblyVersion\("(.*)"\)[>\]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you check my question? I see some differences between vb and cs files. In cs files it start with [assembly, and in vb file it starts <Assembly: so both are different. How can include all?

Comment: Your understanding of *`[variant1|variant2]` syntax*  is incorrect. `[a|b]` matches one of the 3 chars: `a`, `|`, `b`. You must have meant `(a|b)`.

Comment: You are totally right. Round parenthesis would create a capturing group however, so I rewrote the regexp to use [] as a list instead

Comment: Thank you it works now..   $pattern = '(?<!\/\/\s|\''\s)[<\[][Aa]ssembly: AssemblyVersion\("(.*)"\)[>\]]'

Answer (score 1):

You want to "exclude" rows which start either with `/` or `'`.

Start from setting `m` (*multi-line*) flag in you regex.
It ensures that `^` matches start of each **line** (not the whole string).

Then start the regex from:

- `^` - acting now (in multi-line mode) as a *row start marker*,
- `(?!\/|')` - a *negative lookahead* group with two variants
  inside (do not allow that the line starts from either `/` or `'`),
- `\s*` - an optional sequence of spaces.

and then goes your regex.

So the whole regex should look like below:

```
^(?!\/|')\s*\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\("(.*)"\)\]
```

(remember about the `m` flag).

*Negative lookbehind* solution mentioned in other answers has such a flaw
that even if a row starts from `'` or `/` but has **no space** thereafter,
such a regex will fail.